# Footer with variable-height content above it without using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following (http://jsfiddle.net/u2zedzob/1/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.main-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

.footer {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

In this example, `.footer` is placed below `.main-content`, but breaks out of `.wrapper`. I would like `.main-content` to respect the height of `.footer` when determining how tall it can be.

I do not need to support older browsers. Just the latest Chrome/FF.

I can think of a couple of ways to achieve this.

- position: absolute, .footer { bottom: 0 }, .main-content { bottom: 30 }
- .main-content { height: calc(100% - 30px) }
- potentially display: table / display: table-cell with some other fussing?

I don't like the position: absolute solution because it means that if I change the height of `.footer` I have to know to update the bottom value of `.main-content`. Same goes with using calc. I could store a variable in my CSS pre-processor to help assist with this, but it still doesn't feel right.

I've had success with table-cell layouts before for similar scenarios when going horizontally, but I can't seem to get the CSS to work well for vertical.

I'm wondering what approach others would use on this scenario. Thanks

Comment: Position footer to bottom as absolute. Do you really mind if footer covers 30px of your main-content?

Comment: Yep, I do. The scrollbar for main-content would be hidden/shown at unintuitive times. I think the solution might be to use flexboxes, I'm looking into it now.

Comment: If flexboxes are not supported you can default to js to determine the height for main-content;

Comment: As mentioned in the post - I only have to support latest Chrome/FF. I'm building a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use flexboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/u2zedzob/10/

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

.footer {
    min-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```